# sending image file after decamelizing keys in angular reactive form to rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, file-upload, angular8

I want to send an image file to Rails API from angular form alongwith other parameters ( I am using [this tutorial](https://netbasal.com/how-to-implement-file-uploading-in-angular-reactive-forms-89a3fffa1a03) )

But when I decamelize keys using [Humps](https://github.com/domchristie/humps), it removes all the file data attached to image attribute.

Here is my **typescript code:**

```
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    Authorization: environment.apiAuthKey,
  })
};
updateEvent(event: Event): Observable<Event> {
    console.log(event); ##<== file object present, see below in console output
    const eventSnakeCase = Humps.decamelizeKeys(event);
    console.log(eventSnakeCase); ##<= file object disappeared 
    return this.http.put<Event>(url, eventSnakeCase, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
   ...
 }
```

**Output of `console.log(event)`:**

```
{ title: "testing image",
image: File
  name: "DSC_0753.JPG"
  lastModified: 1576224794000
  lastModifiedDate: Fri Dec 13 2019 13:13:14 ... {}
  webkitRelativePath: ""
  size: 6151158
  type: "image/jpeg
}
```

**Output of `console.log(eventSnakeCase)`:**

```
{ title: "testing image",
   image: {}
 }
```

Comment: if wanna attach a file, you have to have `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'` in the header also.

Comment: I changed my header to `const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8; multipart/form-data',
    Authorization: environment.apiAuthKey,

  })
};` 

but still I am receiving  `Parameters: {"title"=>"testing image","image"=>{ } }` on Rails logs